# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at View.render (app.js:70994)

Tags: reactjs

I have made a simple crud app using react with laravel.
Add function is working perfectly but I am unable to view record I got error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
if anyone could help it would be appreciated
here is my code

### Example.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";

export default class Example extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Header/>
           I love React...
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
}
}

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

### Header.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

// import {Link, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route} from "react-router- 
dom";


import View from "./View";
import Add from "./Add";
import Edit from "./Edit";


export default class Header extends Component {
render() {
    return (


        <div className="pos-f-t">
            <div className="collapse" 
id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
                <div className="bg-dark p-4">
                    <h4 className="text-white">Collapsed 
content</h4>
                    <span className="text-muted">Toggleable via 
the navbar brand.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">




            </nav>
        <Router>
            <Link to="/add" className="btn btn-dark" >Add</Link>
            <Link to="/view" className="btn btn-dark" >View</Link>
            <Route exact path="/add" component={Add}/>
            <Route exact path="/view" component={View}/>
            <Route exact path="/edit/:id" component={Edit}/>
        </Router>
        </div>


    );
}
}
```

### View.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route} from "react-router- 
dom";
// import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

// this is used for pagination
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";
//end pagination here

export default class View extends Component {


constructor() {

    super();
    this.state = {

        rssreads: [],

        // this is used for pagination
        activePage: 1,
        itemsCountPerPage: 1,
        totalItemsCount: 1,
        pageRangeDisplayed: 5

        //end pagination here
    }


    this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
}


//didmount is used to render data
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/view').then(response => {
        this.setState({
            rssreads: response.data.data,
            activePage: response.data.current_page,
            itemsCountPerPage: response.data.per_page,
            totalItemsCount: response.data.total,

        });

    });
}

handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    console.log(`active page is ${pageNumber}`);
    this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});

    axios.get('/view?page=' + pageNumber).then(response => {
        this.setState({
            rssreads: response.data.data,
            itemsCountPerPage: response.data.per_page,
            totalItemsCount: response.data.total,
            activePage: response.data.current_page,


        });

    });
}

//ondelete function to delte specific record
onDelete(url_id) {

    axios.delete('delete/' + url_id).then(response => {


        // this code is for live updating data after delete
        var url = this.state.rssreads;

        for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {

            if (url[i].id === url_id) {
                url.splice(i, 1);

                this.setState({rssreads: url});
            }
        }


    });

}


render() {
    return (

        <div>
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Content</th>
                    <th>Link</th>
                    <th>Publish</th>
                    <th>URL</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>


                {

                    this.state.rssreads.map(rssreads => {

                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{rssreads.title}</td>
                                <td>{rssreads.content}</td>
                                <td>{rssreads.link}</td>
                                <td>{rssreads.publish}</td>
                                <td>{rssreads.url}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <Link to= 
   {`/edit/${rssreads.id}`}>Edit</Link>
                                    <a href="#" onClick= 
   {this.onDelete.bind(this, rssreads.id)}>Delete</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>


            <div className="pagination justify-content-center">
                <Pagination
                    activePage={this.state.activePage}
                    itemsCountPerPage= 
   {this.state.itemsCountPerPage}
                    totalItemsCount={this.state.totalItemsCount}
                    pageRangeDisplayed= 
   {this.state.pageRangeDisplayed}
                    onChange={this.handlePageChange}
                    itemClass='page-item'
                    linkClass='page-link'
                />
            </div>


        </div>


    );
   }
 }
```

[This error I got and view page is disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwexl.png)

Comment: `this.state.rssreads.map(rssreads => {` this is the line you are talking about!!!
try to log response.data.data in componentDidMount! And the other place where yo u are making the calls. Make sure it's working correctly.

you are initializing correctly in the constructor, you set it to []. Make sure that in any place it's not turn to undefined.  The object is undefined in place of being an array ([]). You can do (this.rssfeed || []). But that will not take off the problem !!! Make sure the fetched data is handled correctly. Confirm and let us know. console.log  console.log

Comment: wait here is one mistake ` this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});`
here you are resetting all the other properties to undefined. I'm writting an answer that explain that (but you need to do this.setState({...this.state, activePage: pageNumber})

Follow the same logic in all the setState and you'll be ok. Unless you need some properties to be reset to undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.state.rssreads.map(rssreads => {` this is the line you are talking ***about!!!

**Undefined**. Even though you set it in the constructor to an empty array  []. That can mean but only one thing. You are screwing it somewhere. In such a situation the fastest way to find the culprit is to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and search for **setState**.

You'll find the culprit quickly.

But what can be the problem !!! Bad setting of the state. setting only one  without the rest! React **setState()** method **expect the hole state each time** !!

for instance in your code

```
handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    console.log(`active page is ${pageNumber}`);
    this.setState({activePage: pageNumber}); // <------ that's a mistake !!!!!!!!!!

    axios.get('/view?page=' + pageNumber).then(response => {
        this.setState({
            rssreads: response.data.data,
            itemsCountPerPage: response.data.per_page,
            totalItemsCount: response.data.total,
            activePage: response.data.current_page,


        });

    });
}
```

**You should do it this way :**

```
  this.setState({...this.state, activePage: pageNumber});
```

**copy all the state and override only the one property.**

**But what if i want to reset all the state including for example in your code the rssreads !!!!**

```
  this.setState({activePage: pageNumber, rssreads: []});
```

That if the the rest are ok to be undefined!! (and You reset the properties one by one !!!!!)

**If the rest must keep there values :**

```
  this.setState({...this.state, activePage: pageNumber, rssreads: []});
```

**And lastly what if there is many properties and i don't want to go through them all one by one or something.**

**The answer to that :** would be build a function that allow you to create the new state easily. You can think about it. As it will be nice. But well for practice there is libraries for that. And the best that i like is **immer** here it is. So check it out.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer

Here an example:

```
import immerProduce from 'immer';

store.dispatch(setGlobalStates(
    immerProduce(globalStates, (draft) => {
        draft.loadingSpinner.show = true;
    })
));
```

I'm using it within redux. But the important thing, is that the action creator (or just method) `setGlobalStates` is expecting the new state!
With **immer**. You pass the old state here `globalStates`. And then you have the callback and draft that represent the current state. You make the changes in a normal way. mutating normally (in a mutative manner). Then **immer** will figure it out and return the new immutable state. Cool. No hassle and simple.
You use that when you need it. Not always you'll need that.

And lately sometimes the culprit is just in the fetching process itself. When you get the data you don't get it well. So always you have to doubt and check in the end of course if nothing work !!!!!!

And you can always use things like:

```
myVar || defaultValue // if the first undefined the second will take place

myCondition ? thisV: orthis

myList || []

// or simply conditions
thisV && thisB && thisL // if the first is true it evaluate the next one. if true too it will return the last. If one is false the whole thing is false!

if () {} else {}


// in expression and variable binding  you can even do that!

<div>{
(() => {   // <-------------------- an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)
    // my cool processing
    return whatToReturn;
})()
}</div>
```

## spread operator

```
    this.setState({ 
        ...this.state, 
        rssreads: myData || [], 
        otherProp: oneAfterAnotherButOnlyTheOneThatYouNeedToReset,
        //......
    );
```

`...` is the spread operator. In that usage it allow easy merge!

So you are saying grab all the old state, and override or add this and that !

The Equivalent is

```
Object.assign({}, this.state, {rssreads: myData, ..});
```

ref:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

And a note `myData || []`. Mean if the first is a truthy value take it. If it is not and a falsy value use the second! So if myData is undefined then [] will be used. The equiv of `myData || []` is `myData ? myData : []`.

This way the answer is more complete.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200486/discussion-on-answer-by-mohamed-allal-typeerror-cannot-read-property-map-of-u).

Answer (score 0):

As @"Mohamed Allal" suggested debug the places where your setting the state of "rssreads"

for a quick fix: Try this

```
{
      this.state.rssreads &&
        this.state.rssreads.map(rssreads => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{rssreads.title}</td>
              <td>{rssreads.content}</td>
              <td>{rssreads.link}</td>
              <td>{rssreads.publish}</td>
              <td>{rssreads.url}</td>
              <td>
                <Link to={`/edit/${rssreads.id}`}>Edit</Link>
                <a href="#" onClick={this.onDelete.bind(this, rssreads.id)}>
                  Delete
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks **Vanga Kiran Kumar Reddy** I tried this way but did not get the record